# Possible method to insert a whitespace in a string list for between every 4th character in the string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have a list with a bunch of binary values which are in string format. I would like to add a space in between every 4th value so a binary value such as:

```
'111111111111'
```

becomes

```
'1111 1111 1111'
```

For example purposes, lets say my current list is:

```
bin = ['0001', '1111', '111111111111']
```

and I want a new list with the values:

```
new_bin = ['0001', '1111', '1111 1111 1111']
```

How do I iterate over the list and add the necessary white spaces in between every 4th character? The strings which only have 4 characters do not apply and do not need to be adjusted.

Comment: Have you tried and got stuck anywhere?

Comment: Once you've split a string into chunks of 4 (using an answer in the dupe), you can use `join` to patch them together with a space

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over a list or a string in Python using a for loop.
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Then you can just append each character in each string to a list, and at every 4th character you append whitespace. Finally, you join the list by using the string object's `join` method on the list.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Answer (score 2):

this works for me, assuming we have to count from the left: '1111 11', not '11 1111' in case of 6 digits:

```
>>> def add_spaces(a) :
...     result = ''
...     for i in range(0,len(a),4) :
...         if i > 0 :
...             result += ' '
...         result += a[i:i+4]
...     return result
... 
>>> add_spaces('1111')
'1111'
>>> add_spaces('11111')
'1111 1'
>>> add_spaces('111111')
'1111 11'
```

testing with your data:

```
>>> bin = ['0001', '1111', '111111111111']
>>> [add_spaces(i) for i in bin]
['0001', '1111', '1111 1111 1111']
>>>
```